# How to create strategy for Risk to Reward ratio

Tags: pine-script

I am struggling with an R/R ratio strategy. I need a standard 1.5 Win/Lose ratio. As a stop-loss, I am using the low of the previous swing low before the entry level. Here is the code.

```
//@version=4
strategy("TEST","T", true)
    

//₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿  ₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿


fastlen = input(12, "Fast Length", group="MACD")
slowlen = input(26, "Slow Length", group="MACD")
siglen  = input(9, "Signal Length", group="MACD")
mcd_src = input(close, "Source", group="MACD")
_bar    = input(1, "Swing Bar#", minval=1, group="Stop Loss Option")

//₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿  ₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿₿

[fast, slow, hist] = macd(mcd_src, fastlen, slowlen, siglen)

pivot_low_stop  = pivotlow(_bar, _bar)

float entry_lvl = 0.00
entry_lvl := valuewhen(strategy.opentrades == 1, strategy.position_avg_price, 0)
float long_sl = 0.00
long_sl   := valuewhen(strategy.opentrades == 1, pivot_low_stop, 0) 

profit = (entry_lvl - long_sl) * 1.5 + entry_lvl

long = barstate.isconfirmed and fast and slow <= 0 and crossover(fast, slow)

if long
    strategy.entry("Long", true)
strategy.exit("Long", profit=profit, limit=long_sl)



plot(entry_lvl,"Entry Level", color.yellow, 2, plot.style_linebr)
plot(long_sl,"Stop Loss Level", color.red, 2, plot.style_linebr )
plot(profit, "Profit Level", color.green, 2, plot.style_linebr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Pine reference manual:

```
...
profit (float) An optional parameter. Profit target (specified in ticks). If it is specified, a limit order is placed to exit market position when the specified amount of profit (in ticks) is reached. The default value is 'NaN'.
limit (float) An optional parameter. Profit target (requires a specific price). If it is specified, a limit order is placed to exit market position at the specified price (or better). Priority of the parameter 'limit' is higher than priority of the parameter 'profit' ('limit' is used instead of 'profit', if its value is not 'NaN'). The default value is 'NaN'.
loss (float) An optional parameter. Stop loss (specified in ticks). If it is specified, a stop order is placed to exit market position when the specified amount of loss (in ticks) is reached. The default value is 'NaN'.
stop (float) An optional parameter. Stop loss (requires a specific price). If it is specified, a stop order is placed to exit market position at the specified price (or worse). Priority of the parameter 'stop' is higher than priority of the parameter 'loss' ('stop' is used instead of 'loss', if its value is not 'NaN'). The default value is 'NaN'.
...
```

So, your code should be:
`strategy.exit("Long", limit=profit, stop=long_sl)`